# Rebasing a project when the file structure has changed

Tags: python, git, gitlab, rebase

I'm working on a project hosted in Gitlab and I'm using Pycharm
I have my branch which I was working on, while the master branch has changed the file structure, how can I rebase against the new file structure and update my branch with it?

Answer (score 0):

By running `git rebase`. Either Git is clever enough to detect the structural changes and you are done. Or the structure has changed too much and you must resolve the conflicts manually at each commit that is being rebased.

You can try to play around with the `find-renames` strategy option:

```
git rebase -X find-renames=60 master
```